# How can I add an object to a M2M field on my users profile from django rest frameworks class based create view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to have a logged in user add Media to their media field in the users profile in a DRF generic create view.  Has anyone tried this?  Here's my view and model:

```
class MediaCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
"""
    To create a media object, send a post request to:
        /profiles/media/create/
    In the format:
        Audio: "audio file upload"
        Title: "char field"
"""
queryset = Media.objects.all()
serializer_class = MediaSerializer



class Musician(ProfileModel):
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    media = models.ManyToManyField('Media', blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.user.username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to do this with a function api view instead so I can add the model to the profile using the request and not requiring any get request
I know the check if method == Post is redundant but it doesn't harm anything:

```
   @api_view(['POST'])
   def MediaCreate(request):
       context = {}
       logged_on = False
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
          logged_on = True
          visitor = request.user.musician
          serializer = MediaSerializer(data=request.data)
          if request.method == "POST":
              if serializer.is_valid():
                 serializer.save()
                 try:
                    x = serializer.instance
                    visitor.media.add(x)
                    context['upload'] = True
                 except:
                    error = "Media Not Added to Profile"
                    context['logged_on', 
                             'error', 
                              'upload'] = logged_on, error, False
                    return JsonResponse(
                                      data=context,
                                  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
      context['logged_on'] = logged_on
      return JsonResponse(data=context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do define in your **serializers.py** the two classes:

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Media

class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    media = MediaSerializer(many=True, read_only=true)

    class Meta:
        model = Musician
```

In order to update the media field for specific musician you send only the media_id and not the whole object as show the following example:

```
data = {
    "summary": "text summary here"
    "company": "Company A"
    "media_id": 3 
}
```

in your **views.py** you should define the following view and override get_object to fit your needs:

```py
class MusicianUpdatingApiView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """
    To add a media to a user, send a post request to:
    /profiles/:id/media
    """
    serializer_class = MusicianSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        summary = self.request.data.get("summary")
        company = self.request.data.get("company")
        media_id = self.request.data.get("media_id")
        musician_id = self.kwargs['id'] # cause it send in the url
        data = {
             "summary": summary
             "company": company
             "media_id": media_id 
        }
        updated_musician, created = Musician.objects.update_or_create(
                id=musician_id,
                defaults=data
            )
        return updated_musician
```

in **urls.py**

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<id>\d+)/media$', MusicianUpdatingApiView.as_view()),
```

Comment: no this works for update too, the serializers just define the relations and how data should be returned or stored, it's up to you to define your views and how they behave. I updated the code for more details.

Comment: It worked, but since it needs the pk on the end of the url I went with the method below.  I'm trying to limit the number of calls over the network my application will need to make so my app will use the least amount of data possible.  This will be the first mobile application I have made so I may be building in unnecessary features, I assume I can just store the users pk on the users' device cache or something

Comment: The url design I shared is a best practice, and it's used by Ruby on Rails, Django and recommended by many developers. You need the musician information anyway,and I'm sure you have the ok somewhere, you should not have to request it again. And yes, you can save it in a cache, **SQLite**, **Couchbase Lite**, or even in [Localstorage](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/local-storage/106).
I will recommend also to read [this article](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/), it will confirm you my approach.

Comment: I think in this case the way I ended up doing it in the method above is the easiest way to accomplish what I need accomplished.  However, I am attempting to use the UpdateView in some other features and keep getting csrf errors